# Default url for area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

How do I specify a default action for an area

I have defined my area and its working ok

```
/admin/
```

however if I browse to /admin/ directly it seems to hit standard controller and not the area and there is no standard controller area thus it 404's

Is there a way to specify the area has a default controller / action or do I need to define a custom route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by specifying the `area` in `RegisterArea`

```
 public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
 {
        context.MapRoute(
            "admin", // Route name
            "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "YourControllerName", action = "YourActionName", area = "admin", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
}
```

Now if you browse to `admin`, it will redirect directly to the action specified in `RegisterArea`